# What database to use for fast data records with a fixed number of columns

Tags: database, opencv

I have a constant number of columns - they correspond to real-time coordinates of a few/maybe even a few hundred points in space (constant id and x, y coordinates of a detected pose in an OpenCV image - they are analyzed grid by grid so a lot of data comes in at once).

I read that Redis runs on RAM and you can set a time to delete the data.

Cassandra stores data in columns next to each other so as for fixed coordinates it should be suitable.

It would be nice if you could perform operations on them such as subtraction or multiplication.

I'm looking for a database that will be able to quickly write and read this data and at the same time will not be performance-intensive.

thanks

Comment: "database"... why? just keep the data in a data structure in your own program. both C++ and python's fundamental data structures are just fine to hold a few hundred points.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz but this data is lost when the program is closed, and I would like it to be available, and the history of captured movements by OpenCV preserved

Comment: ok so store it. you don't need a database for that, just a file.